# Why does changing the text within the TextChanged event of a RichTextBox control does not cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

This is a question about the C#winform form program.

Recently, I found the following code when I looked at my old code:

```
        richTextBox1.TextChanged +=
            (x, y) =>
            {
                string indentation = "\t\t";
                string output = "";
                foreach (string str in richTextBox1.Lines)
                    output += indentation + str+"\r\n";
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Text = output.TrimEnd('\r','\n')));
            };
```

I think this code will cause the stack to overflow, so I ran it, but it worked fine.So, I wrote the following test code:

```
        button1.TextChanged +=
            (x, y) =>
            {
                button1.Text += "Nay";
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => button1.Text += "Neko"));
            };
        richTextBox1.TextChanged +=
            (x, y) =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += "Nay";
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Text += "Neko"));
            };
        this.Load +=
            (x, y) =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "Test";
                button1.Text = "Test";
            };
```

ps : These codes are located in the Form constructor of the WinForm program.

My question is:
Generally speaking, in the TextChanged event of control C, changing the Text property of control C will cause the stack to overflow, but the RichTextBox control will not. Even if you change its Text property in the TextChanged event of the RichTextBox control, TextChanged will not be triggered. I am curious why this is happening?

The controls I tested:
Form control / Label control / ListBox control / ComboBox control / Button control / CheckBox control / GroupoBox control / DataGridView control and other controls.

Thank you all for your comments on this question.

Comment: RichTextBox does not use the standard implementation of the text field. The event `TextChanged` is inherited from a base class. That is the reason, that `TextChanged` is not triggered.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Your comment makes it sound like the TextChanged event doesn't get triggered for a RichTextBox.  It does.

Comment: My guess would be because the RichTextBox is actually updating the Rtf property.  Somewhere in that process it's avoiding the recursion issue that the TextBox faces.

Comment: @LarsTech: I checked it. You are right. I thought, TextChanged is not triggerd because it was written in the question. `RichTextBox control, TextChanged will not be triggered`.